# How to redirect root blog to a specific one in multilang WP?

Tags: multisite, redirect

After installation I've got a default root blog '/'. Then I've created a new one '/en'. I really don't want to use the default blog. How can I redirect all accesses from / to /en ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file in the main '/' directory, put:

```
# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/en/
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting, just move the site you want into the old one:

1. Remove all pages, posts and taxonomies from the old unwanted site, and empty the trash to clear the database fields.
2. Export the content from your new preferred site.
3. Download and install the WordPress Importer plugin, and import your content into the main site in your network.
4. Install your plugins, enable theme, change settings, etc. to match the other site.
5. Once everything is how you would like it, delete the second site, and redirect it to the freshly rebuilt one.

To redirect matching pages, use a rule like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /en/(.*)? http://jeffsebring.com/$1
```